# Powershell command from php over ssh

Tags: php, windows, powershell, ssh, cmd

I would like to run a remote powershell command from my php server using the ssh library.

It all work for a simple command like :

```
$code = str_replace("/","\\",'PowerShell Move-Item -Path '.SOURCE.' -Destination '.TARGET);
ssh_cmd($username, $userpass, $code);
```

Where ssh_cmd is a function that initiate the connection and write the command.

I would like to do a more "complex" command, that is supposed to use libreoffice to convert docx files to pdf from a specific foled as follow:

```
$code = str_replace("/","\\",'PowerShell Get-ChildItem "'.SOURCE.'" -Filter *.docx -Recurse -File| foreach-Object {
    set-location $_.directoryname
    write-host ($_)
    write-host ($_.FullName)
    write-host ($_.DirectoryName)
    &("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe") --convert-to pdf -outdir $_.DirectoryName $_ | Out-Null  
}');
ssh_cmd($username, $userpass, $code);
```

but I have the returned error :
**& was unexpected at this time. PowerShell**

I tried that command directly on the remote server using PowerShell and it worked fine.
I just saw that at each line of the above command it add **>>** at the beginning of each lines.

Do you have any idea when I am wrong here ?

**[edit]**
Thanks to Sammitch I understood that i was still in CMD when i tought that by simply adding powershell first was processing the command in powershell. I was wrong.

here is an updated code :

```
    $code = 'powershell.exe -noexit "Get-ChildItem \''.SOURCE.'\' -Filter *.docx -Recurse -File| foreach-Object {set-location $_.directoryname | &(\'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe\') --convert-to pdf -outdir $_.DirectoryName $_ | Out-Null  }"';
    echo ssh_cmd($username, $userpass, $code);
```

So it is basically a cmd command that launch the powershell process with provided cmd. Works fine now.
**[/edit]**

Thank

Comment: arguments not escaped?

Comment: You're not running `Get-ChildItem ...` in Powershell, you're running `PowerShell ...` in `cmd.exe`, which is what is complaining about a rogue `&`. You'll need to either escape all that for `cmd`, or figure out how to make SSH start Powershell directly rather than `cmd`.

Comment: Thank you both. The hint were usefull. Actually I have update the script after understanding that i was still in cmd and should find a way to run Powershell from c. I have updated the inital post with the new code.